# How to build code using MSBuild.exe from comand line without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

Can you please explain step by step how to build code using command line without Visual Studio and generate DLL?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I need sample file(.sln,.csproj) which is going to using with MSBuild and need command that I can compile code without Visual Studio and generate DLL.

Comment: You mean without Visual Studio *installed* on the machine? Of you have it installed, but want to use command line?

Comment: I mean, I want to compile/Build code using MSBuild commandline and generate DLL without using Visual Studio(IDE) from .sln and .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution.

```
Please do following steps to generate DLL from xml file without having Visual Studio IDE.

Basically, we require only two types files

1. class file like Helloworld.cs , Welcome.cs
2. XML file

Here below is the format of XML file which helps to generate DLL file

     <Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <!-- Generate DLL/Assembly Name -->
    <AssemblyName>MSBuildSample</AssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>  
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
       <!-- Mentioned here class file to compile  -->
        <Compile Include="Helloworld.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Welcome.cs" />
        <!-- <Compile Include="C:\testing\test.Designer.cs" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="C:\testing\test.resx" /> -->
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" 
             Resources="@(EmbeddedResource)" 
             References="@(Reference)" 
             TargetType="library"
             OutputAssembly="C:\testing\test.dll" />
    </Target>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Save this file as MSBuild.xml in same folder where your class file reside and then you need to run following command from Command Line

```
MSBuild.exe MSBuild.xml /property:Configuration=Debug
```

This will helps you to compile and  generate DLL from XML file without having Visual Studio.

This is very basic .xml file but you can complie and generate dll file from  your project file (.csproj) file too. You just need to add following lines if not exists in that .csproj file.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType> 
  <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath> 
 </PropertyGroup>
```